# Dropped keys in Keyword.Merge/3 function

Tags: elixir

When I call the following function, {:a, 2} in Keyword list 1 is never gets transferred, however {:b, 4} in List 2 gets transferred to the resulting list even though there's no matching pair Keyword List1. Anyone known why?

`iex> Keyword.merge([a: 1, a: 2, b: 2], [a: 3, b: 3, b: 4], fn _k, v1,v2->v1+v2 end)`

`[a: 4, b: 5, b: 4]`

What makes it even more weird for me is that, in the following merge {:a, 2} gets transferred to the resulting list

`iex>Keyword.merge([a: 1, a: 2, b: 2], [b: 3, b: 4], fn _k, v1,v2->v1+v2 end)`
`[a: 1, a: 2, b: 5, b: 4]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s a tricky question.

**TL;DR:** this is done to make it consistent with [`Keyword.merge/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html#merge/2).

---

This excerpt from [Elixir tests](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.6.2/lib/elixir/test/elixir/keyword_test.exs#L147) demonstrates the issue:

> ```
> fun = fn _key, _value1, value2 -> value2 end
> [...lots of arg1 and arg2 declarations...]
> assert Keyword.merge(arg1, arg2) == Keyword.merge(arg1, arg2, fun)
> ```

The fix might be easy: just `s/delete/delete_first` [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.6.2/lib/elixir/lib/keyword.ex#L741):

```
- do_merge(tail, acc, delete(rest, key), original, fun, keywords2)
+ do_merge(tail, acc, delete_first(rest, key), original, fun, keywords2)
```

but that way the normal merge function (without the resolver) would behave differently. I am going to check if `Keyword.merge/2` might be adapted to conform the expected behaviour and maybe fill a bug / provide a PR.

---

**FWIW:** https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/7420 was closed by José saying:

> To quote the docs:
>
> > A keyword may have duplicated keys so it is not strictly a key-value store.
> >     However most of the functions in this module behave exactly as a dictionary so they work similarly to the functions you would find in the `Map` module.
>
> In this case, it means that what goes on the right side does remove everything on the left side. The same way that `Keyword.put` removes all other entries, instead of simply prepending to the keyword list. :)

Answer (score 2):

It is right.
In the first exmaple,

```
A = [a: 1, a: 2, b: 2]
B = [a: 3, b: 3, b: 4]
Keyword.merge(A, B, fn _k, v1,v2->v1+v2 end)
```

`B`'s `{a: 3}` will match the first a in A, so `fn` will apply to solve conflict. `A`'s second `a` has no match, which will be dropped.
Then, `B`'s `{b: 3}` will match `A`'s `{b: 2}`, will also apply `fn` to solve conflict.

Note that

> including duplicated keys, given in keywords2 will be added to
>   keywords1

, thoug `B`'s `{b:4}` has no match, it will add to A.

So the result is `[a: 4, b: 5]` add `{b: 4}`, which is `[a: 4, b: 5, b: 4]`.

---

Second example,

```
A = [a: 1, a: 2, b: 2]
B = [b: 3, b: 4]
Keyword.merge(A, B, fn _k, v1,v2->v1+v2 end)
```

As there are no matching keys in `B`, so `A`'s `[a:1, a:2]` will be not overriding and kept.

`B`'s `{b:3}` will match `A`'s `{b:2}`, so use `fn` to resolve conflict, res is `{b: 5}`. `{b: 4}` has no match and will be kept.

So res is `[a: 1, a: 2, b: 5, b: 4]`.

---

You can also have look at the example of `Keyword.merge`'s doc.

```
Keyword.merge([a: 1, b: 2, a: 3], [a: 3, d: 4, a: 5], fn :a, v1, v2 ->
...>  v1 + v2
...> end)
```

For this one, `a` and `b` have two matches and will apply one by one.
The res is `[b: 2, a: 4, d: 4, a: 8]`.

Comment: Thanks but I was also wondering if there's a reasoning behind this behavior